# VS Code tsserver problem matcher overwrites errors from custom task problem matcher

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have written a custom task that uses the $ts-webpack-watch problem matcher from the [TypeScript + Webpack Problem Matchers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.tsl-problem-matcher) extension. The problem matcher associated with tsserver that runs automatically within VS Code appears to be overwriting the contents of the Problems view populated by my custom task's problem matcher rather than appending to it. The tsserver problem matcher only applies to open files, whereas the $ts-webpack-watch problem matcher applies to all files in the project, which is what I want.

If I restart the running custom task in VS Code, the correct information appears in the Problems view.

Is there a way to make the Problems view append data from multiple problem matchers? Failing that, is there a way to disable the problem matcher for the tsserver task that automatically runs in VS Code (in other words, stop tsserver from running)?